# What causes macOS Music app to freeze on NAS stored media files?

Tags: music, catalina, nas, drobo

Using macOS Music (formerly iTunes), I have a library with database files stored on the local drive and some media files stored on a Drobo 5N NAS device.

In macOS Catalina, any attempt to modify the metadata of certain files will cause the Music app to freeze. I have to force quit. Sometimes, the Music app won't start up again and I have to restart the machine.

This seems to affect the following file types:

- mp3
- itlp (iTunes LP)

m4a files work fine. (I haven't comprehensively tested the file types supported by Music. Maybe there are others that trigger a freeze.)

A freeze also happens if I attempt to add one of these file types, my media folder is on the NAS, and I have the "copy files to Music Media folder" setting checked.

The file size or metadata content does not seem to matter. Files stored in the local hard disk do not have any issues. Playback of the files works fine.

Tested using multiple fresh Music libraries under multiple users on the same machine (a 2017 iMac), got the same result. Tested on another machine (a 2017 MacBook), and had no issue (!).

[Edit: found the difference between these machines. The MacBook was running 10.15.1, but the iMac was running 10.15.2. Updated the MacBook, now it can reproduce the error. So this is a regression introduced by 10.15.2.]

I recall having similar issues prior to Catalina, but on the other hand at some point I was able to make metadata changes without issue.

Here's the frozen stack:

```
  41  start + 1 (libdyld.dylib + 108541) [0x7fff6aed67fd]
  41  ??? (Music + 3235896) [0x10f43d038]
  41  -[NSApplication run] + 707 (AppKit + 201695) [0x7fff30a323df]
  41  ??? (Music + 15804463) [0x11003982f]
  41  -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1072 (AppKit + 1988908) [0x7fff30be692c]
  41  routeKeyEquivalent + 521 (AppKit + 8149915) [0x7fff311c6b9b]
  41  -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] + 348 (AppKit + 3742832) [0x7fff30d92c70]
  41  -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 106 (AppKit + 3747022) [0x7fff30d93cce]
  41  -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 312 (AppKit + 3747666) [0x7fff30d93f52]
  41  -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 299 (AppKit + 2641944) [0x7fff30c86018]
  41  ??? (Music + 15805693) [0x110039cfd]
  41  ??? (Music + 11478256) [0x10fc194f0]
  41  ??? (Music + 9948278) [0x10faa3c76]
  41  ??? (Music + 17065457) [0x11016d5f1]
  41  ??? (Music + 10192576) [0x10fadf6c0]
  41  ??? (Music + 14998996) [0x10ff74dd4]
  41  ??? (Music + 15005773) [0x10ff7684d]
  41  ??? (Music + 19437052) [0x1103b05fc]
  41  ??? (Music + 19298751) [0x11038e9bf]
  41  ??? (Music + 19297109) [0x11038e355]
  41  ??? (Music + 20463913) [0x1104ab129]
  41  ??? (Music + 6345239) [0x10f734217]
  41  ??? (Music + 5255339) [0x10f62a0ab]
  41  ??? (Music + 5257381) [0x10f62a8a5]
  41  ??? (Music + 7491303) [0x10f84bee7]
  41  ??? (Music + 11434264) [0x10fc0e918]
  41  ??? (Music + 11435170) [0x10fc0eca2]
  41  ??? (Music + 11430705) [0x10fc0db31]
  41  ??? (Music + 6485926) [0x10f7567a6]
  41  ??? (Music + 20222962) [0x1104703f2]
  41  ??? (Music + 14311715) [0x10fecd123]
  41  ??? (Music + 15740833) [0x110029fa1]
  41  ??? (Music + 15734858) [0x11002884a]
  41  ??? (Music + 2609221) [0x10f3a4045]
  41  ??? (Music + 2598046) [0x10f3a149e]
  41  ??? (Music + 2599072) [0x10f3a18a0]
  41  ftruncate + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 15494) [0x7fff6b019c86]
 *41  hndl_unix_scall64 + 22 (kernel + 930310) [0xffffff80002e3206]
 *41  unix_syscall64 + 650 (kernel + 7974074) [0xffffff800099acba]
 *41  ftruncate + 440 (kernel + 3859880) [0xffffff80005ae5a8]
 *41  mac_vnode_notify_truncate + 115 (kernel + 9159075) [0xffffff8000abc1a3]
 *41  qtn_taint_vnode_if_needed + 198 (Quarantine + 22592) [0xffffff7f81447840]
 *41  quarantine_getinfo + 167 (Quarantine + 23066) [0xffffff7f81447a1a]
 *41  mac_vnop_getxattr + 244 (kernel + 9196420) [0xffffff8000ac5384]
 *41  vn_getxattr + 1097 (kernel + 3926409) [0xffffff80005be989]
 *41  afpfs_vnop_getxattr + 586 (afpfs + 164844) [0xffffff7f8503f3ec]
 *41  GetExtendedAttributes + 407 (afpfs + 72539) [0xffffff7f85028b5b]
 *41  UserCommand + 45 (afpfs + 50303) [0xffffff7f8502347f]
 *41  DoUserCommand + 1987 (afpfs + 49058) [0xffffff7f85022fa2]
 *41  UserReply + 148 (afpfs + 46860) [0xffffff7f8502270c]
 *41  ??? (kernel + 7072322) [0xffffff80008bea42]
 *41  asp_tcp_usr_control + 2758 (asp_tcp + 8980) [0xffffff7f84ffb314]
 *41  Reply + 391 (asp_tcp + 23301) [0xffffff7f84ffeb05]
 *41  msleep + 98 (kernel + 6936066) [0xffffff800089d602]
 *41  ??? (kernel + 6934620) [0xffffff800089d05c]
 *41  lck_mtx_sleep_deadline + 115 (kernel + 1363251) [0xffffff800034cd33]
 *41  thread_block_reason + 175 (kernel + 1425135) [0xffffff800035beef]
 *41  ??? (kernel + 1431281) [0xffffff800035d6f1]
 *41  machine_switch_context + 200 (kernel + 2490504) [0xffffff8000460088]
```

Any ideas how to address this?

Comment: You found the issue and it was a faulty update.  The only way to fix it is for Apple to fix it in a subsequent update.  You might also want to give them some feedback:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/